# Task without Virtual Warehouse: Is the query failing or the task not starting?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When you create a task in Snowflake, you also have to pass a Virtual Warehouse that is used for the execution.

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] TASK [ IF NOT EXISTS ] <name>
  WAREHOUSE = <string>
...
```

Regarding this topic I wondered about the scenario when someone drops the Virtual Warehouse later.

```
DROP WAREHOUSE <name>
```

Will the task start anyway and the query fails (because it has no associated warehouse) or will the task not even start because of the missing warehouse in his definition?

My expectation is that the task is starting but the query fails immediately.

More information about creating tasks: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html

Comment: Hi - I'm wondering why you are asking this question? What impact will it have on your processes whether the task doesn't start or the query fails? What is stopping you spending 5 minutes trying this in your Snowflake environment?

Comment: What is stopping me: My priviliges on that account ;-)

Comment: You should ask your Snowflake Admin to create a DB that you have ownership of and allow you to create/drop warehouses :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task will be fail with error "Cannot execute task , USAGE privilege on the task's warehouse must be granted to owner role", also you can check task execution status under:

```
select *
from table(information_schema.task_history()) 
where DATABASE_NAME = 'DEMO_DB'
order by scheduled_time;
```